# How to search for some specific links(which may be present in a pdf file) in a website and crawl those links for other information?

Tags: python, parsing, web-crawler

I have a task to complete. I need to make a web crawler kind of application. What i need to do is to pass a url to my application. This url is website of a government agency. This url also having some links to other individual agencies which are approved by this government agency. I need to go to those links and get some information from that site about that agency. I hope i make myself clear.Now i have to make this application generic.  It means i can't hard code it for just one website(government agency). I need to make it like any url given to it , it should check it and then get all the links and proceed. Now in some website these links present in pdfs and in some they are present on a page.

I have to use python for this. I don't know how to approach this. I spend time on this using BeautifulSoup but that require lots of parsing. Other options are scrapy or twill. Honestly i am new to python. I dont know which one is better for this task. So any one can help me in selecting the right tool and right approach to solve this problem. Thanks in advance

Comment: it seem that your requirements are too vague, what does `I need to make it like any url given to it , it should check it and then get all the links and proceed` means? suppose it mean extracting all links from an html page and request all of them, what are you going to do with their responses?

Answer (score 1):

There is [plenty](https://www.google.com/search?q=python+web+scraper&oq=python+web+scraper&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l3.2234j0j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) of information out there about building web scrapers with Python.  Python is a great tool for the job.

There are also tons of posts about web scrapers on this website if you search for them.